# Command line arguments for console app are getting truncated on one machine and not another

Tags: .net, console-application

I wrote a console application to run automated tests for my companies web application. The applications takes parameters such as Env=qa Browser=Chrome and Clients=Clientname1,ClientName2,ClientName3. When I run the application on my machine it works fine, but when I run it on a Windows Sever 2012, the clients param is being truncated to the first client.

Here is the code I am using to parse the command line argument out and store it to a list :

```
static List<string> ParseList(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        List<string> Collection = new List<string>();
        string SplitResults = arg.Split('=')[1];
        if (SplitResults.Contains(','))
            Collection = SplitResults.Split(',').ToList();
        else
            Collection.Add(SplitResults);

        return Collection;
    }
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that each comma separated value in the list was being considered its own argument by the program. If you construct and argument in such a way, you have to add double quotes around the comma separated list.